# External Volume Control for Laptop

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio

I recently bought a new HP laptop and it doesn't have physical volume control buttons (increase/decrease/mute). I sometimes forget to mute my volume before going to public places and I was wondering if there are any inexpensive USB devices which I could hook up to my laptop that would let me increase/decrease the volume. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean. You can carry around a set of headphones and have those plugged in when you boot. This will prevent the sound coming from the speakers.

If you don't care about having a set of headphones to drag around, just find the absolute cheapest pair or from Radio shack and just purchase the little 3.5mm jack to plug in. This will act the same and fool your laptop.

PS. laPtop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a HP laptop with the same issue. Try this program called [Sound Control](http://www.reallyeffective.co.uk/sound-control/). It allows you to create hot keys to increase, decrease, and mute your laptop's volume.